# Rewrite Rules and Expires-Header with Apache/nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, expires-header

I come today with a problem of browser caching static files.

I have a Prestashop Website on a Plesk server running with Apache and Nginx.

Prestashop generates a .htaccess file with apache rewrite url rules :

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
```

And Nginx was set up to add expires-header to static files :

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    try_files $uri @fallback;
}
```

This will works for static files that their urls were not rewrote by Apache :

url example :  http://www.domain.tld/modules/homeslider/images/image_name.jpg

> ```
> Server: nginx
> Date: Sun, 20 Nov 2016 19:32:33 GMT
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
> Content-Length: 50616
> Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 14:47:22 GMT
> Connection: keep-alive
> ETag: "582dc2fa-c5b8"
> Expires: Tue, 20 Dec 2016 19:32:33 GMT
> Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
> Pragma: public
> Cache-Control: “public”
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
> ```

But Not for product's images that their urls were rewrote by the apache rules :

url example : http://www.domain.tld/156-home_default/image_name.jpg

> ```
> Server: nginx
> Date: Sun, 20 Nov 2016 19:34:11 GMT
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
> Content-Length: 7587
> Connection: keep-alive
> Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 21:14:27 GMT
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
> X-Powered-By: PleskLin
> ```

The question is : How to make the nginx expires-header apply to files urls rewrote by the Apache Rewrite rules ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The server management is handle by Plesk 12.5.

nGinx is used to handle static files. I don't know much about its configuration.

In Plesk domain.tld -> Nginx configuration, I checked "Smart static files processing" and "Serve static files directly by Nginx". And in "Additional Nginx directives", I added the expires-header code. That's all modification I have done on this. It's as default plesk configuration.

**RE-EDIT**

nginx vhost configuration file :

```
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

server {
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 ssl;

    server_name domain.tld;
    server_name www.domain.tld;
    server_name ipv4.domain.tld;

    ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/certP286MBP;
    ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/certP286MBP;

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    root "/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs";
    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.tld/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.tld/logs/proxy_error_log";

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7081;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log off;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7081;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/plesk-stat/ {
        proxy_pass https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7081;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/(.*\.(ac3|avi|bmp|bz2|cue|dat|doc|docx|dts|eot|exe|flv|gz|htm|html|img|iso|mkv|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|pdf|ppt|pptx|qt|rar|rm|svg|swf|tar|tgz|ttf|txt|wav|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|zip))$ {
        try_files $uri @fallback;
    }

    include "/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.tld/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
}

server {
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;

    server_name domain.tld;
    server_name www.domain.tld;
    server_name ipv4.domain.tld;

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    root "/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs";
    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.tld/logs/proxy_access_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.tld/logs/proxy_error_log";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log off;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/plesk-stat/ {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/(.*\.(ac3|avi|bmp|bz2|cue|dat|doc|docx|dts|eot|exe|flv|gz|htm|html|img|iso|mkv|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|pdf|ppt|pptx|qt|rar|rm|svg|swf|tar|tgz|ttf|txt|wav|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|zip))$ {
        try_files $uri @fallback;
    }

    include "/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.tld/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context, like full sample URL and more nginx configuration? Also, I guess that nginx is routing requests with Apache being an upstream?

Comment: @JanPapenbrock, Thank for your reply. I edited the answer.

Comment: both example above have the "Server: nginx" reply, so those are being served by nginx. What you need is to put your location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ { earlier in your nginx config file, because order matters.

Comment: I added the nginx configuration file in a new edit. The use of `PT` flag in the apache rewrite rules did not help. Also, as you see, I can't modify the order of the nginx rules because it's an auto-generated file.

Comment: When you cannot change nginx configuration, you could add the appropriate cache rules to `.htaccess` instead. Would that be possible, can you edit `.htaccess`?

Comment: @JanPapenbrock Yes I can. That was the first try. The rules are already in the file but not applied... I think because of nGinx who handles Static files. I'm kind of stuck with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this. Not a big mystery...

I did convert the rewrite rules from apache to nginx and ignore the .htaccess.

That did the trick.

The new "Additional nginx directives" :

```
# Deny all for hidden files/directory (.htaccess, .htpasswd, etc...)
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
rewrite ^/images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

location ~* \.(gif)$ {
    expires 2592000s;
}
location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg)$ {
    expires 2592000s;
}
location ~* \.(png)$ {
    expires 2592000s;
}
location ~* \.(css)$ {
    expires 604800s;
}
location ~* \.(js|jsonp)$ {
    expires 604800s;
}
location ~* \.(js)$ {
    expires 604800s;
}
location ~* \.(ico)$ {
    expires 31536000s;
}
location ~* \.(woff)$ {
    expires 2592000s;
}
```